# Can't make POST request using Swift

Tags: swift, http, post

I have code like this:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://myurl.com/webservice2/save_stamps.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "facebook_id=x&pin=1234&count=1"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    request.setValue("keep-alive", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")
    request.setValue("text/html", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        println("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume()
```

In xCode console I can see:

```
response = <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7ff91950de90> { URL: http://myurl.com/webservice2/save_stamps.php } { status code: 200, headers {
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Length" = 20;
"Content-Type" = "text/html";
Date = "Fri, 07 Aug 2015 08:41:10 GMT";
Server = "Apache/2";
Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
} }
responseString = Optional()
```

I try to change count=1 using &count=1 but nothing changes.
Where is the problem?

Maybe there is another way to simply call http without getting any data?

Comment: What is the error? The console states the request completed without an error. But why are you posting text/HTML and want to have keep-alive?

Comment: I try to do this with different ways. Now I removed two request.setValue and It still not working.

Comment: Can you successfully send a request using e.g. curl? If yes, you can dump and compare the actual requests e.g using http://requestb.in

Comment: I can successfully make request using my browser. But In code isn't working.

Comment: I suggest you use Alamofire and SwiftyJSON if you dont mind

Comment: Alamofire doesn't change this value too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
func httpPost(url:String, postData: String, completion: String -> Void) {

        var googleUrl = NSURL(string: url)

        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: googleUrl!)

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        request.HTTPBody = postData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

            completion(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String)

        })

    task.resume()

    }
```

It can be used so:

```
httpPost("http://myurl.com/webservice2/save_stamps.php", postData: "facebook_id=x&pin=1234&count=1") { result in

            println(result)//result is your string-response from server

        }
```